# Organizing template-like code without templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates, cmake

I have a parent package which implements a class 'goody' and has the following structure:

```
parent/include/goody.h
parent/src/goody.cpp
```

This package is used by several children packages child_1 to child_n with structure

```
child_i/include/child_details.h
child_i/src/main.cpp
```

where main.cpp uses 'goody'. The important part is that child_details.h provides information to the parent that is necesary for the implementation of 'goody'.
goody.h lookes something like:

```
#include "child_details.h"
class goody
{
  double arr_[child_details::num_elements];
}
```

where 'num_elements' is a constant and needs to be known at compile time.

Now, I know that templates would be the right construct to use for this kind of problem, but (a) I do not want to add specializations into every child_i package and (b) 'num_elements' is all over the place in the parent package and would require a lot of template specific code, which I would like to avoid.

My question thus is: What is a clean way to organize the my packages with CMake? I cannot compile the parent package inside of parent, because there will be an instance of 'goody' for each child. On the other hand I would like to avoid compiling all of those instances inside of parent, because parent is not supposed to know about the children. Is there something like an uncompiled object that I can generate inside of the parent package, which then has to be compiled in each of the child packages?

Comment: Just to make one thing clear: each of the children ends up in a separate executable, right? Because if you link any two children with a different number of elements together, you'll be violating [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule), making the whole thing illegal C++.

Comment: You are adding separate specialization in each child _anyway_, because you have to compile it separately for each different "child_details.h".

Comment: @Angew each child is a separate package and has its own make.cpp and its own child_details.h .

Comment: @Jan You are right, that I add specialized information into child_details.h, but in my case this header file is given anyways. In the scenario where I would use templates, I had to add a goody_specialized_i.cpp into each child package in order to specialize 'goody'. This would be a much bigger overhead, since I had to do this for each class in parent and each child.

Comment: @Alex: No, you don't. You specialize `goody` by simply using it. And the amount of code generated is exactly the same in both cases.

Comment: @Jan In the scenario I presented, I only have to add a constant 'num_elements' into cild_details.h and "add_library(parent_goodies parent/src/goody.cpp)" to child_i/CMakeList.txt . In your scenario, however, I would have to define 'template <int num_elements> class goody'in the parent package and specialize it with 'template class goody<child_details::num_elements>'. This is more anoying to maintain if I add another 'goody2' class into the parent package. On top of that I would clutter the parent package with templated code.

Comment: @Alex: It's not more annoying; you trivially hide it behind a typedef. And it actually makes sense unlike your solution for which the maintenance programmer who'll come after you will curse you to hell, because it's totally non-obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `goody.h` is part of the `parent`, it should not include `child_details.h`. You could instead have a `goody_child` template, but you can have a non-template `goody_base` object that implements everything except those things that are dependent on child properties. The child properties can be known through a virtual functions implemented by `goody_child`.

```
class goody_base {
public:
    //...
    virtual double * arr () = 0;
    virtual size_t num_elements () const = 0;
    //...
    void print_arr () {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < num_elements(); ++i) {
            std::cout << arr()[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    //...
};

template <typename DETAILS>
class goody_child {
    double arr_[DETAILS::num_elements];
    //...
public:
    double * arr () { return arr_; }
    size_t num_elements () const { return DETAILS::num_elements; }
    //...
};
```

Then, your child code could do something like this:

```
#include "goody.h"
#include "child_details.h"

typedef goody_child<child_details> goody;
```

There is no template specialization when the code is organized in this way.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, most of the 'goody' class is dependent on child_details.h . If I had to separate 'goody' into code that does depend on child_details.cpp and code that does not, the non-dependent code would be very little. That would mean that most of the code I would have to write into each of the childs.

Comment: I am looking more into a solution on the level of package organization rather than on code level. I was wondering if there is something like a container of source files that I can generate in the parent packageand and then in the child package I would compile this container with the proper include of child_details.h .

Comment: @Alex: Either make a template code in headers and simply include it as needed or generalize the code properly so the code can be compiled once and linked to all the child packages. The later is preferred, because it will save quite a bit of time during the build. But compiling the code multiple times over with different compiler options (include path in your case) will just make it difficult to understand for anybody who comes after you and will have absolutely no advantages over proper template.

Comment: I wanted to avoid templates, because it clutters the code in the parent package, but I guess you are right that the code becomes less transparent, if the specialization is happening on the compile level. Probably, I will have to swollow the pill and just go for templated code. Thanks a lot guys!